# UDF decimal to binary

Tags: c++, binary, console-application, converters

I wrote a decimal to binary converter function in order to practice my manipulation of number systems and arrays. I took the int a converted it to binary and stored each character, or so I beleive, in an array, then displayed to the screen, however it is displaying characters I do not know i looked them up on the aski table and do not recognize them, so i would like to ask for your assistance, here is a picture of the code, and console app.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the next time, use markdown to put sourcecode in the question, not use screnshots.

Comment: @Manu343726 i know but i also wanted to show the console app running along with the results, and just decided to post everything as one, but duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to insert number chars (such as `'1'`) in your result, but you assign the char value. Try adding the value of `'0'` to get a readable result (`remainder + '0'`).

If you interpret the result array as a string (that's what i suggested), you should also set the last char to the value `0` (not `'0'`!) to mark the end of the c string.

Answer (score 0):

Your output function not correct output your binary text because:

1) cout output characters until '\0', so your function will correct output until get first 0 in binary representation of int (for example for 5 = 101 it will output only one smile with code 0x01).

2) your last character in array is not '\0', so cout will output garbage until '\0' or memory access exception.